# How following derivation is carried out.

Tags: probability, derivatives

[image]

Can anyone explain how equation (3) came from equations (1) and (2). I know some derivation is used, but how?

Comment: Can you write them out.. the link isn't working.

Comment: Thanks For Quick Response. Try This Link "http://imgur.com/a/T0Dvd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the simple use of

$\frac{f(t+dt)-f(t)}{dt}=\frac{df}{dt}$